# Does the instruction printf(“%4.2f”, num); display four digits including two decimal places?

Tags: c++

In C++, does the instruction `printf("%4.2f", num);` display four digits including two decimal places?

Comment: Can't you just make a small program to test this?

Comment: What does your class-notes say? The tutorials you have read? The text-books you have? The [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) available? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You could have easily read about the printf and format specifier. It isn't hard to find from already existing sources, and there are good ones.

Comment: write a test one liner (ideone.com if you dont have a compiler) and update the question with the answer

Comment: By the way, please don't use the old C function `printf` in C++. It's not type-safe and you can easily enter the realm of *undefined behavior* way to easily. If you don't have any decent books, then [here's a list of good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), I really recommend you invest in a few.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude always sad when I see a reference to a really useful question that would now not be permitted

Comment: @pm100 Life was easier before we all got so strict. :) On the other hand, a community as big as this with so many new users would fall into chaos immediately without some strictness.

Answer (score 5):

> The instruction `printf("%4.2f", num);` displays four digits including two decimal places?

No, that is not how it works.

A format string is specified in the following format:

`%[flags][width][.precision][size]type`

Specifiers in `[]` are *optional*.

The *width* specifier indicates the *minimum number of characters* to output **total** (it may be more!).  If not specified, the *width* defaults to 1.

The *precision* specifier indicates how many digits the `f` *type* prints after a decimal point (the *precision* has other meanings for different *type*s).  If not specified, the *precision* defaults to 6 for the `f` *type*.

In your example format string: `%4.2f`, `4` is the *width*, `2` is the *precision*, and `f` is the *type*.

So, for example, given `double num = 123.0;`:

```
printf("%f", num);
```

Has a *width* of 1 and a *precision* of 6, so it prints `"123.000000"` - *at least* 1 character, including the decimal and 6 digits following the decimal.

```
printf("%4.2f", num);
```

Has a *width* of 4 and a *precision* of 2, so it prints `"123.00"` - *at least* 4 characters, including the decimal and 2 digits following the decimal.

```
printf("%10.2f", num);
```

Has a *width* of 10 and a *precision* of 2, so it prints `"    123.00"` - *at least* 10 characters, including 4 leading spaces added as padding, the decimal, and 2 digits following the decimal.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/WK7wIz)

Refer to [this `printf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for more details about the format string and its inputs and outputs.

Comment: incorrect the width specifies the min width of the field, it is padded with spaces if needed https://ideone.com/rLgO1A

Comment: Nevermind. I have fixed my answer

Comment: friend I'm poor in programming, just tell me if it's true or false

Comment: @Eindid It is false. How do the examples in my answer, particularly the 2nd example, not address that question for you?

Answer (score 0):

The 4 is the width of the field and the 2 after the point is the precision specification for the float that you want to print. But it also depends on what is the value of num. So, no it is not guaranteed to be 4 digits. If num is 234342.43, then it is not going to be 4 digits.

Comment: friend I'm poor in programming, just tell me if it's true or false

Comment: @Eindid I have suggested an example that it is not going to be four digits. So the answer is false. In any case, you could have written a program involving just a few lines to see this for yourself.